# TFS project layout with teams using different work methods

Tags: tfs

We'd like to set up TFS2012 to handle the multiple work methods per project problem. Did see the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866843/tfs-2010-team-projects) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134452/tfs-project-collection-layout-suggestions-and-good-practices-for-multiple-team), but I think our case is different.

We have several products with one or more teams working on them. The teams see the product's backlog, but they may use different work method - a project can have a scrum and a kanban team. In some cases a kanban team does release work on the user stories which are finished by the scrum teams.

How should we start setting up TFS to have different work methods (templates) within a project? Should we use one project collection? Is there a template which can handle scrum and kanban work together Can we modify and map a workflow to two different boards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each team project is based on a single process template. In this case you can either choose the [Scrum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff731587.aspx) or the [Kanban](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj838789.aspx) template, and [customize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd286521.aspx) it.

It seems [Scrumban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Scrum-ban) process would fit into your project, however there's process template available yet for TFS.

Comment: Thanks KMoraz! Probably modifying the scrum template would be the solution for us. Do you have any information, that different teams in a project can have different boards? Eg.: The scrum team and the release scrumban team can have different board mappings?

Comment: By default, mapping works on the team project level, not the team level. However you can try the [Customizable Kanban Swim Lanes](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2013/mar-4/) that was introduced in [TFS 2012 update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912)

Comment: Thank you KMoraz. Yes, the new kanban swimlanes allowed me to do some team-specific changes, but it is still quite strict as the state categories (eg.: Waiting for upload can't be in the first column of the upload team while it is mapped to the "Complete" type ). Anyway thanks for the ideas!